# Adding constrain to UIView to bottom of UIView for iPhone has notch

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

How to add UIView to the bottom of UIView using constraints

```
    bottomView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:leftMenuView.frame.height - 64, width: leftMenuView.frame.size.width, height:64))

    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    leftMenuView.addSubview(bottomView)

func setUpBottonViewConstrain(){

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant:-64),
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
}
```

Working fine in iPhone 5s but in iPhone12  has-notch its not fixed to bottom

Comment: use `bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.bottomAnchor)` remove `safeAreaLayoutGuide` it will fix to bottom assuming your leftView is fixed to bottom of screen else apply similar constraint to `leftMenuView` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func setUpBottonViewConstrain(){
    guard let superview = superview else { return }
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        bottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftMenuView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant:-64),
        bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```